# Checking "value equality" of mutable classes in unit tests

Tags: c#, .net, mstest

In a project, I have several classes that are mutable.

In unit tests using MSTest, I'd like to check whether objects of those classes are what I expect, which basically means comparing some fields and properties of the objects, i.e. value equality.

As I understand, if I want to use `Assert.AreEqual` and `CollectionAssert.AreEqual` etc., I'd have to override `Equals` (and maybe implement `IEquatable`) and do the comparison of the fields and properties there.

But then, as I understand, to make sure nothing bad happens when somebody else uses these classes, maybe in a hash set, I have to override `GetHashCode`. But (according to several questions and answers on Stackoverflow) overriding `Equals` so that it provides value equality, and overriding `GetHashCode` for mutable classes cannot be done correctly.

Thus, in unit tests, how can I check that objects of mutable classes are kind of "value equal"?

Comment: It's not completely verboten to have a mutable class which provides an identity - see for example [`System.Drawing.Point`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.point?view=net-7.0) but it's inadvisable. But you can just implement an [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=net-7.0) to pass to the assert methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with overriding `GetHashCode` is that if you use the object in a hashSet or dictionary, and mutate the object, the dictionary/hashset will not work correctly.

A workaround for this is to instead implement a [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=net-7.0). That reduces the risk of bugs, since anyone using a dictionary would have to do extra work to specifically use your `MyValueEqualityComparer`.

This EqualityComparer should be possible to use in the `Assert.Equals` Method, at least in the latest version of MSTest

```
Assert.Equals( a, b, new MyValueEqualityComparer());
```

Comment: The latest `<PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="3.0.2" />` NuGet package (the official Microsoft one) does have a version of `Assert.Equals()` that accepts an `IEqualityComparer<>`  parameter.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Not using the latest version was my issue, too. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @MatthewWatson Thanks, I apparently found the wrong documentation page.

Comment: They don't seem to have updated the documentation online at all!